# Divide output of wc-l by 4 in a for loop in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, divide, fastq

I'm trying to write a for loop that unzips fastq.gz files that contain R1 in the file name, determines # of lines in each file, and divides # of lines by 4. Ideally I could also write this into a txt file with two columns (file name and # of lines/4).

This loop unzips R1 fastq files and deterimnes # of lines in each file but does not divide by 4 (or save output into a txt file).

```
for i in $(ls ./*R1*);
do
gzcat ./$i | wc -l
done;
```

Other posts on here suggest using bc to divide in bash, but I haven't been able to integrate this into a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Your loop will fail for filenames with spaces or any other special characters. For most circumstances, you simply iterate over the files with `for i in path/*; do ...`, but understand that can fail if the filenames contain the `'\n'` character as part of the name. The optimal for handling all  filenames is to use `find` as `while read -r name; do ... done < <(find path -type f -name "*.gz")` (note *process substitution*, `< <(...)` is a bash only construct, pipe to the loop if using POSIX shell)

Next, to write the name and number of lines / 4 to a new file, wrap your entire loop in a new scope between `{ .... }` and simply redirect all output at once to the new file.

You should also add validations to check if the file is a directory ending in `gz` and skip any found, as well as skipping any empty file (zero file size)

If you it altogether, you could do something like:

```sh
{
for i in R1/*.gz; do
  [ -d "$i" ] && continue                 ## skip any directories
  [ -s "$1" ] && continue                 ## skip empty files
  nlines=$(gzcat "$i" | wc -l)            ## get number of lines
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" $((nlines / 4))  ## output name, nlines / 4
done
} > newfile         ## redirect all output to newfile
```

(output is written with a `tab` character `"\t"` separating the name and number / 4 -- adjust as desired)

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I was able to get all of your suggestions to work except for the printf function. I used echo instead and re-directed to a new file

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your scripting!

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way to do integer arithmetic is using the `$((...))` notation, as you can see from these simple examples:

```
Prompt> echo $((2*6))
12
Prompt> echo $((20/4))
5
Prompt> echo $((21/4))
5
```

It can also be used in combination with other commands, like `wc -l`:

```
Prompt> cat .viminfo | wc -l
287
Prompt> echo $(($(cat .viminfo | wc -l) / 4))
71
```

Answer (score 0):

I know those bioinfomatics datasets are gigantic, but in the ultra off-chance you encounter one with fewer than 1024 rows, then simply :

```
% [g/n/m]awk 'BEGIN{ 
                    _ = system("exit $(( 977 / 4 )) ")
           print _ }'
    244
```

It's the ultra lazy way of doing things by leveraging the fact there are `256` typical exit codes one can choose from, which is the only thing `system()` function is willing to return -

this way, you don't need all the extra overhead involving getline and closing the command and pipe.

Comment: Unfortunately none of my files with have fewer than 1,024 rows. Thanks for the input though

Answer (score -1):

This would work, if you allow that 5 / 4 = 1 (so rounded down to the nearest integer). If you want to work with decimals (5 / 4 = 1.25) then you'll need `bc` or `awk`

```
for i in $(ls ./R1); do 
  nb_lines=$(gzcat ./$i | wc -l)
  echo $((nb_lines / 4))
done;
```

Comment: Why not `printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "$nb_lines"` to write the filename and number of lines? Also, Never use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) Instead `for i in R1/*; do` or use `find R1 -type f` and use that as input for a `while read -r name; do` loop.